# How do I delete objects within objects in Angular-Meteor?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, object, meteor, angular-meteor

NOTE: the following code and demo are extracted from a larger Meteor + Angular project.

---

I have the following functions to select and delete objects:

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qi8nIPEd2aeXOzmVR6By?p=preview

```
  $scope.selectParty = function(party) {
    $scope.party = party;
    $scope.type = party.type;
    $scope.date = party.date;
  }

  $scope.deletParty = function(party) {
    $scope.parties.remove(party);
  }

  $scope.selectOrganizer = function(organizer) {
    $scope.organizer = organizer;
    $scope.name = organizer.name;
    $scope.title = organizer.title;
  }

  $scope.deletOrganizer = function(organizer) {
    $scope.party.organizers.remove(organizer);
  }
```

The Select action works on both Parties and Organizers as you can see in the demo, displaying the data in the table underneath.

The Delete action doesn't work. Although, let me point out that in my app, the one I have on my machine and currently working on in Meteor, the Delete action works splendidly on Parties, meaning the syntax "`$scope.parties.remove(party)`" works. But it doesn't work on the plnkr demo for some reason :(

My question is really about the Organizers Delete action, where I'm targeting an object (`organizer`) inside an array inside the selected object (`party`)… that one doesn't work. I'm wondering why, and what is the right syntax.

NOTE 2: I'm aware of Angular's `splice` and `index` but I can't use them here as I'm not simply working with Angular arrays but with database data in Meteor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The organizer is a part of the party object and not a collection on it's own. So what you would need to do is remove the party from the object and then save the party object.

Note2 is incorrect. Unless you wrote your question and plunker wrong.